# web scraping IMDb in python

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping

I'm going through an old Harvard CS 109 class and can't get the ratings from the 250 most voted on movies in the database. I THINK my problem is that there are two `td.ratingColumn`s, one with the rating and another--right after--that asks you to rate the movie. The 2nd `td.ratingColumn` contains no `</strong>`. Would that give me my error? How do I adjust the code to get all of the ratings? 9.2 is 1/250. Thanks.

```
dom = web.Element(r.text)

for movie in dom.by_tag('td.ratingColumn'): 
    rating = runtime.by_tag('strong')[0].content 
    print rating

9.2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ca9164c76716> in <module>()
      2 
      3 for movie in dom.by_tag('td.ratingColumn'):
----> 4     rating = movie.by_tag('strong')[0].content
      5     print rating

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have pointed out, since the second element doesn't contain the  tag, an empty array is returned which raises an `IndexError` exception when trying to access first element.

This should work:

```
if movie.by_tag('strong'):
    # do stuff
```

Let me know if I missed out something.